# python 2.7 weird unicode re.sub behavior

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I'm writing a program to normalize csv header columns. It might occur that the column contains a non-English character, so I added the `re.UNICODE` flag to my `re.sub` calls.

My code looks like this:

```python
 for i in range(0, len(row)):
    column = row[i]
    column = column.lower()
    column = re.sub('[\W]', '_', column, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
    column = re.sub('[_]{2,}', '_', column, flags=re.UNICODE)
    column = column.strip('_')
    print column
```

In my current scenario I have one column with a non-English character: `Printer geïntegreerd`. The encoding of the originating file is UTF-8. I'm not writing the result to a file yet, just writing to console.

The column gets converted to: `printer_ge�_ntegreerd`.

When I leave the `re.UNICODE` flag, it gets converted to: `printer_ge_ntegreerd`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the encoding of your file and the terminal? Are you opening the file with the right encoding? Are you writing the results with the right encoding?

Comment: Right, it's all UTF-8. Also updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using "utf-8" encoding and got the wanted result:

```
for i in range(0, len(row)):
    column = row[i].decode('utf-8')
    column = column.lower()
    column = re.sub('[\W]', '_', column, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
    column = re.sub('[_]{2,}', '_', column, flags=re.UNICODE)
    column = column.strip('_')
    print column
```

When you read input from a file it's of type str with a specific encoding, when you try to manipulate it using "re" it uses the default decoding "ascii". This is not the correct encoding in your case, the most common encoding is "utf-8" and "latin-1" which transform the variable to type unicode. "re" recognise the characters correctly in variables of type unicode. 
Note that after the decoding column is of type unicode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works! Could you explain why the `decode` needs to be done?